# @Param not working in Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, kotlin

I'm setting up a Spring Data JPA Repo to work with sequences in a postgresql database. I was assuming that this would be pretty simple:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS ':seq_name' START WITH :startAt")
fun createSequence(@Param("seq_name") seq_name: String, @Param("startAt") startAt: Long = 0)

@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT nextval(':seq_name')")
fun nextSerial(@Param("seq_name") seq_name: String) : Long

@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "DROP SEQUENCE IF EXISTS ':seq_name'")
fun dropSequence(@Param("seq_name") seq_name: String)

@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "setval(':seq_name', :set_to, false")
fun setSequence(@Param("seq_name") seq_name: String, @Param("set_to") setTo: Long)
```

But for some reason I get 
`org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter with that name [seq_name] did not exist;` whenever I'm trying to call the method. Any idea why this might happen?

Comment: Same happens when using ?1 to access the parameter

Comment: which version of spring-data-jpa do you have on classpath?

Comment: Just remove the ' chars e.g. `@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT nextval(:seq_name)")`

Comment: removing the ticks works for the select query. For the create query I now get a `org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet`

Comment: Probably because you're parameterising something which cannot be parameterised, such as the sequence name.

Comment: 1) don't quote bound parameters 2) `SELECT setval(...)` (the `SELECT` is important there too) 3) `CREATE/DROP SEQUENCE` uses the sequence name as an identifier. you cannot bind identifiers in any way. 4) *SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet* is just a wrapper exception, dig deeper in the `cause` chain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, based on the answer from @StanislavL and after some debugging around I have a working solution now. As @posz pointed out I cannot bind identifiers which means I have to hard code the queries. I moved the code from a JPA interface to an implemented service which is not as nice but works.

```
@Service
open class SequenceService (val entityManager: EntityManager){

    @Transactional
    fun createSequence(seq_name: String, startAt: Long = 0) {
        val query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS ${seq_name} START ${startAt}")
        with(query){
            executeUpdate()
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    fun nextSerial(seq_name: String) : Long {
        val query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT nextval(:seq_name)")
        with(query){
            setParameter("seq_name", seq_name)
            val result = singleResult as BigInteger
            return result.toLong()
        }

    }

    @Transactional
    fun dropSequence(seq_name: String) {
        val query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("DROP SEQUENCE IF EXISTS ${seq_name}")
        with(query){
            executeUpdate()
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    fun setSequence(seq_name: String, setTo: Long){
        val query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT setval(:seq_name, :set_to, false)")
        with(query){
            setParameter("seq_name", seq_name)
            setParameter("set_to", setTo)
            singleResult
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this is helpful for the next person trying to directly work with sequences when using `@SequenceGenerator` is not an option.